# Increase text size programmatically depending on screen density and screen size

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-screen-support

I would like to avoid creation of multiple layouts for different screen resolutions. I was thinking to adjust the text size programmatically depending on screen density and resolution. So, I would like to increase/decrease text size if the size of the screen increases/decreases.  Text must take the same percentage of the screen.

I tried to do something like this for medium sized text of 18sp:

```
textView.setTextSize(18 * getActivity().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
textView.setText("Some text");
```

The text becomes bigger on larger density screens and that looks fine on bigger devices but on small devices with big density text is really really big.

How can I programmatically change text size depending on screen size and screen density? Thank you.

Comment: Have you looked at using the `sp` unit when defining the textSize in your layouts?

Comment: Yes but when I use sp unit text on my cell phone is ok and on my tablet is really small compared to size of the device.

Comment: Perhaps rather than using density then, you should be doing a percentage of total pixels?

Answer (score 1):

Try doing something like this (play with using width or height to get the results you are looking for):

```
Point size = new Point();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getSize(size); 
float percent = .18f;
textView.setTextSize(percent * size.x); // size.x = screen width in pixels
```

**EDIT**

If using API < 13 you can do the following:

```
int width = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
```

Comment: Thx. This `getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getSize(size);`  requires at least API13 and I am supporting API10 so I need to find some kind of an alternative.

Comment: +1, thanks. I am using that text inside FragmentList. I think I need to change list item size first and then I will see how it will behave.

Answer (score 0):

I think using "sp" in font size performs pretty well in this case .

Comment: "sp" gives me the same text size on my cell phone and on my tablet.

Comment: Hmm It worked for me on different devices with different screens , but I haven't tested it on tablets so I'm not really sure about that . Hope you'll find a solution :)